# VB.NET - Export image saved as bytes to excel

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, image

In VB.NET, how to export image saved as bytes in sql database to excel (image should be displayed in excel)?

Comment: what so far you done?? post your tried code

Comment: Flagging this as _too broad_. Please see [ask] and consider taking the [tour].